# Assigning default values if NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an MVC app where a user can select company benfits, there are 10 different benefits and they can have none up to all 10 of these. In my view I have the ten listed with radio buttons to indicate whether they are required or not. There is also a calculation performed in the controller that adds all the values together to give a total.

As an example in my controller -

```
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceRequired = viewModel.LifeAssuranceRequired;    
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceSchemeName = viewModel.LifeAssuranceSchemeName;
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceProviderName = viewModel.LifeAssuranceProviderName;
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceBenefitLevel = viewModel.LifeAssuranceBenefitLevel;
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceEmployerCost = viewModel.LifeAssuranceEmployerCost;
newuser.LifeAssurance.LifeAssuranceEmployeeCost = viewModel.LifeAssuranceEmployeeCost;
```

Since the user may decide not to choose this benefit is it possible to assign the cost as 0 if they have not made a selection in the view model? Can I check if it's null and add 0 in that case?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `??` operator (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28VS.80%29.aspx))
use it  like this:

```
string someString = null;
string someOtherString = someString ?? "0";
```

if someString(or any other object) is not null use it, else use whatever is on the right of the `??` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe set your values as `nullable` by add `?` to type, and then you can check it is null by:

```
var someValue = (nullableValue.HasValue) ? nullableValue.Value : 0;
```